# how to call external java script file after partial postback

Tags: javascript, asp.net, partial-postback

I am facing problem with external java script file after using of UpdatePanel in asp.net, that I have 2 images in datalist and that two images will get slide with external javacript file and I have dropdown separately by changing that values in dropdown new images will bind to that datalist and after that external javascript file should load for sliding the images, but it's not happening because datalist is in `UpdatePanel` so that my page won't get refresh because its partial post back.

```
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel4" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <asp:DataList ID="MultiImgDataList" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Flow">                              
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <div class="magnify">
                                    <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" CssClass="img" ImageUrl=<%#Eval("Path") %>/>
                                    <asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" CssClass="img" ImageUrl=<%#Eval("Path") %>/>
                                </div>
                            </ItemTemplate>                              
                        </asp:DataList>                       
                    </ContentTemplate>
                    <Triggers>
                        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Dropdown1" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
                    </Triggers>
       </asp:UpdatePanel>

 <asp:DropDownList ID="Dropdown1" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Dropdown_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:DropDownList>



   <script src="/Scripts/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
```

But when I change dropdown the external script not calling so the sliding is not happening, I know this is because of partial post back but I need updatepanel and also need process of calling external javascript file. How to solve this ??

Comment: Please share some code. There is no way to see what you are really doing.

Comment: i have added  code, please look at it. @navigator